# What is the best distance metric for places

Tags: java, user-input, levenshtein-distance

I'm searching for a "good" / easy metric to recognize similar places / user input to **avoid crreating duplicates**.

Levenstein distance works good for Typos like

> bakery
>
> bekerry

(Levenstein Distance: 2)

But "fails" for swapped words

> St Ursula School
>
> School St. Ursula

(Levenstein Distance: 17)

and additions

> Serious Business
>
> Serious Business Incorporated

Comment: Strikes me that you are trying to work out what the place names mean.  Probably you need a simple parser to read the names.  In real life often "small street, SE1" and "small street, E1" are often confused.  I wouldn't expect an automated process to be perfect

Answer (score 0):

I think using the raw distance metric will be hard. You probably want to use some NLP methods (nltk) to do ner (named entity recognition), then use that result to compare.